# Handling relations when mapping DTOs to EF entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi, dto

In my DTOs, I send Ids instead of entire objects to assign/relate one object to another. The problem is my mapping code will need access to the database to handle this because my entity classes don't have `BarId` property.

```
public class FooDTO
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public int BarId { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

This can probably be solved by adding additional `BarId` property to my entity class, that way I don't couple data access with my mapper.

But the question arises: if bar with specified id doesn't exist can this be handled in some reasonable way to return the custom error message?

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public int? BarId { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Is it fine to access database in my mapping code and handle these assignments manually or is it better to leave it to the ORM by explicitly adding a foreign key property (`BarId`) in my entity class?

Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#no-foreign-key-property

> While it is recommended to have a foreign key property defined in the dependent entity class, it is not required.

It seems like adding foreign key property is recommended so I guess I will choose this route.

Comment: *Is it fine to access database in my mapping code* -- or use `foo.Bar?.BarId`.

Comment: @GertArnold When querying yes, but when updating there is a problem because you need to find `Bar` by `BarId`. That requires the mapper to query the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, not fine. if you are accessing the db this is most definitely not mapping code.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought.